# Python: index 4557 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4557

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, lstm, indexoutofboundsexception

I am using lstm for weather prediction, in google colab using python and tensorflow & panda.
The snippet of code that gives error is in the creation of univariate model as follows(image attached as well):

```
univariate_past_history = 20
univariate_future_target = 0

x_train_uni, y_train_uni = univariate_data(uni_data, 0, TRAIN_SPLIT,
                                           univariate_past_history,
                                           univariate_future_target)
x_val_uni, y_val_uni = univariate_data(uni_data, TRAIN_SPLIT, None,
                                       univariate_past_history,
                                       univariate_future_target)
```

The error is

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-b832595cabf2> in <module>
     4 x_train_uni, y_train_uni = univariate_data(uni_data, 0, TRAIN_SPLIT,
     5                                            univariate_past_history,
----> 6                                            univariate_future_target)
     7 x_val_uni, y_val_uni = univariate_data(uni_data, TRAIN_SPLIT, None,
     8                                        univariate_past_history,

<ipython-input-5-fd6d6cf9af09> in univariate_data(dataset, start_index, end_index, history_size, target_size)
    11     # Reshape data from (history_size,) to (history_size, 1)
    12     data.append(np.reshape(dataset[indices], (history_size, 1)))
---> 13     labels.append(dataset[i+target_size])
    14   return np.array(data), np.array(labels)

IndexError: index 4557 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4557
```

[Error][1]

The function used above is as follows:

```
def univariate_data(dataset, start_index, end_index, history_size, target_size):
  data = []
  labels = []

  start_index = start_index + history_size
  if end_index is None:
    end_index = len(dataset) - target_size
  for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    indices = range(i-history_size, i)
    # Reshape data from (history_size,) to (history_size, 1)
    data.append(np.reshape(dataset[indices], (history_size, 1)))
    labels.append(dataset[i+target_size])
  return np.array(data), np.array(labels)
```

The data I am using is 4558*16 csv file in which some values are zeros and other are empty as well.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3QIy.jpg

Comment: Size 4557 means the index of the last element is 4556 (since indexing starts with zero).

Comment: The first code snippet added in the question is the part where the error occurs, the second is the error and the third code is the function used in the first code added. Please let me know if there are any accessibility issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we can create a simple frame that will have 5 rows. Note that indexes start from zero in pandas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    i for i in range(5)], columns=['x'])
```

Result:

|  | x |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |

If we check the `size` of this dataframe, we will get a response of 5 because there are five rows:

```
>>> df.size
5
```

What happens if we try to access something at the index position of 5?

```
>>> df.iloc[5]
IndexError: out-of-bounds
```

This is telling us that we are trying to access an index in out DataFrame that is outside what is acceptable. In our simple example here, the frame has a size of 5 and has 5x rows but it does not have an index position of five.